Assigning students to courses based on two first choices and two reserve choices and having a limit on number of students per course
Let's say I have a list of 160 students randomly listed, they have to choose a course (from Courses 1-7), with different limits on maximum student numbers per course, e.g.
Course 1: 30 students max
Course 2: 23 students max
Course 3: 29 students max
Course 4: 24 students max,
Course 5: 25 students max
Course 6: 23 students max
Course 7: 22 students max
Each student lists their two 'first' choices and their two 'reserve' choices.
The two first choices have equal weighting, as do the two reserve choices.
The aim is to assign students to one of their two first choices as long as the maximum student numbers per course are not exceeded. Otherwise, students are assigned to one of their reserved choices.
In the image (file also included), I'm looking for results in the yellow cells. Students' choices are in columns B-H (1 for either of the two 'first' choices, R for either of the two 'reserve' choices). I need to get the assigned course in column J (I've added some as an example) and the choice in column K (1 or R). I also need to get the number of students per course (column N) considering the limits in column O.
Have you guys worked on anything similar and have any ideas on what formula(s) to use?
image of working Excel file
working Excel file
I tried using the IF, COUNTIF, XLOOKUP functions in a way similar to the one below (column numbers are different, 'first choices' are labelled as 1 and 2). This indeed gave the students one of their first two choices, but I cannot control the number of students per course and this formula doesn't actually consider reserve choices.
=IF(COUNTIF($U$1:$U1,XLOOKUP(1,$M2:$S2,$M$1:$S$1))<24,XLOOKUP(1,$M2:$S2,$M$1:$S$1),XLOOKUP(2,$M2:$S2,$M$1:$S$1))

For M11:N13, are those primary and reserve counts supposed to be for each class, or just a total student count (countifs(K:K,M12))?

Did this using a combination of countifs() with the class size limits and catching the remainders. Then using index() with match() to brings names across in each sheet representing a particular class. Also had a block with running counts to keep track of how many chose each subject.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The formula is not your problem. You need the algorithm to solve this task. As soon as you provided the algorithm, the society will try to help with realization.

Here's an attempt
With REDUCE

using accumulator to hold the assigned class, choice and current availability for each class:
HSTACK(course_choice, updated_count)
when assigning a class, assign the one that has more places left
IFS(AND(c_1, c_2), IF(c_1 > c_2, i, j)...

=LET(
    avaliable, TRANSPOSE(V2:V8),
    student_choices, B2:H161,
    classes, SEQUENCE(, 7),
    reduce_count, LAMBDA(i, arr, arr + -1 * (i = classes)),
    assign_class, LAMBDA(acc, r,
        LET(
            avaliable, DROP(TAKE(acc, -1), , 2),
            assign, LAMBDA(chosen_pair,
                LET(
                    i, INDEX(chosen_pair, 1, 1),
                    j, INDEX(chosen_pair, 1, 2),
                    c_1, INDEX(avaliable, 1, i),
                    c_2, INDEX(avaliable, 1, j),
                    IFS(
                        AND(c_1, c_2),
                        IF(c_1 > c_2, i, j),
                        c_1, i,
                        c_2, j,
                        TRUE, 0
                    )
                )
            ),
            choices, INDEX(student_choices, r, ),
            first, assign(FILTER(classes, choices = 1)),
            second, assign(FILTER(classes, choices = "R")),
            course_choice, IFS(
                first,
                HSTACK(first, 1),
                second,
                HSTACK(second, "R"),
                TRUE,
                {"-", "-"}
            ),
            updated_count, IFS(
                first,
                reduce_count(first, avaliable),
                second,
                reduce_count(second, avaliable),
                TRUE,
                avaliable
            ),
            VSTACK(acc, HSTACK(course_choice, updated_count))
        )
    ),
    assigned, REDUCE(
        HSTACK(0, 0, avaliable),
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(student_choices)),
        assign_class
    ),
    VSTACK(
        HSTACK("Assigned course", "Choice", "Count " & classes),
        DROP(assigned, 1)
    )
)


